# HTTP Response code for expired (but not necessarily permanently expired) URL

Tags: iis, http-status-codes

We have client galleries on our website that are supposed to be available to a certain amount of time.  Once the gallery is no longer available, I want to redirect people to a URL that says that the gallery is expired.  We also want to ability to turn a gallery back on if necessary.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement that behavior.  Is a 302 redirect the best way?  Is it reasonable to do a redirect in the first place (rather than displaying the expired message at the same URL)?  At this point it's a static site, but it's on an IIS (v. 6) box, so I'd be doing something ASP.NET based if I needed a programmatic solution.

Comment: For ease of implementation, I've gone with a 403 for now...

Answer (score 3):

try 307. It's a temporary redirect, as opposed to a permanent one. once you're sure you're not using a gallery anymore, you could convert it to a 301.

see more on the subject here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Is there a way to get that to happen via IIS, or will I need to do that programmatically?

Comment: I personally like using HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect. You may be able to do it in IIS, I've never tried. But you can always just throw something like this in a .aspx file in the folder the gallery lived in: 
<script runat="server">
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-url.com");
}
</script>